# Time complexity of string repetition (via str * int)

Tags: python, string, time-complexity, big-o

What's the time complexity of repeating a string in python with the String * int operator?

To be clear, I'm talking about this phenomenon:

```
print("a"*4)
```

would output "aaaa"

I tried to find an answer myself, but can't find anything about this, and it's worse because I am unsure of what it's called... I'm just calling it string repetition for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this lecture](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~pattis/ICS-33/lectures/complexitypython.txt), given an integer `k` and a list `l`, `k*l` is of complexity `O(k*N)`.

Since strings are iterables too, I assume the answer is the same for strings.